# Новостной блог на Джумле

Tags: content, menu, joomla

Привет всем. Недавно начал учить Джумлу, так что не ругайте сильно если спрашиваю что-то не по теме))

Короче, надо сделать так, чтобы

1. при добавлении статьи в "Content Manager"-е, на первой странице слева (в сайдбаре) тут же отображалась ссылка на новый материал (+прокрутить страницу автоматически к этой новой статье) и, если можно, превью этой статьи.
2. Статья сама появлялась на странице "Новости" первой по счету.

Это возможно? Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Раз вы начали учить Джумлу недавно, то рекомендуется прекратить это гиблое дело.

И начать учить программирование, ну или на худой конец РНР.

Comment: @SilverIce а PHP это типа ацтой, на PHP не программируют?

Comment: PHP - это язык программирования, то есть инструмент.

Если я вам дам кирпичи, ведро и мастерок, это ж не сделает из вас строителя, правда )))

Comment: @SilverIce, вы думаете что будет проще написать собственный новостной движок чем изучить стандартный? :))
P.S. С чето тогда, по-вашему, надо начинать изучать Джумлу?

Comment: Нада же, какой-то лашок поставил минус)) (нет бы отписаться что не нравится)))

Comment: @alex_90 кто-то видно слишком умный и родился программистом знающим Joomla XD)  Обнулил)

Comment: @Palmervan
Добавил +1. Ну так, поржать.

@alex_90 
Зачем изучать Джумлу? Её нужно ставить и пользовать, если она вам нравится.
В мире есть куча интересных вещей которые можно познавать - ООП, альпинизм, гидродинамику, женщин )))

Comment: @Palmervan , @SilverIce спасибо за советы. Однако вопрос с новостной лентой остается еще открытым))

Comment: Ололо, я учу Joomla!

> Нада же, какой-то лашок поставил минус))

@SilverIce, похоже это просто школота. И да, на Joomla! не программируют, и ОП отправляется либо на БитКод, либо читать инструкцию.

Comment: Не соглашусь. Западные фриланс-сайты [забиты вакансиями Joomla! Developer](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=joomla+developer&l=&relative=1) . Потому что из коробки любая популярная CMS (в том числе Drupal, Wordpress) предоставляет весьма посредственные возможности. Можно, конечно, говорить, что расширения Joomla! пишутся на PHP, но используется API Joomla! Поэтому тема вполне в контексте форума программистов. Поставил плюс.

Comment: joomla написана на php, собсно что мешает допилить ее? т.е. заняться программированием)))
или разработчики joomla нубы?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было сделать так: создать категорию "Новости" и при добавлении новой статьи ставить эту метку. Затем создать в меню страницу типа "блог категории" и выбрать эту категорию. В настройках отсортировать по дате публикации по убыванию. Затем создать новый модуль (сайдбар) типа "Материалы - Список материалов категории" и выбрать эту же категорию.